# ¿Como guardar los datos recibidos en mi objeto Author y acceder a sus propiedades con Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular

En `Nodejs` tengo esta funcion que devuelve el autor a traves de su id

```js
export const getAuthorById = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    try {
        const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
        const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM authors WHERE id_author = $1', [id]);
        return res.json(response.rows);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Ha ocurrido un error al intentar obtener el autor por id'
        });
        // return res.status(500).json('Internal server error');
    }
}
```

aca mi `author.service.ts` en **Angular**

```js
URL_API = 'http://localhost:4000/authors';

getAuthorById(id: string): Observable<Author> {
    return this.http.get<Author>(`${this.URL_API}/${id}`);
  }
```

este es mi modelo `Author`

```js
export interface Author {
    id_author: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Aca mi componente `books.component.ts`, donde quiero guardar el resultado que trae `authorService.getAuthorById()` en mi objeto **autor**
de **tipo "Author"** y asi poder acceder a sus propiedades `autor.id_autor y autor.name`

```js
autor: Author;

getAuthorbyId(id: string) {
    this.autor = this.authorService.getAuthorById(id);
    //console.log('el nombre del autor es: ' + this.autor.name);
  }
```

Pero Angular muestra este error: **ERROR in src/app/admin/components/books/books.component.ts:116:5 - error TS2739: Type 'Observable<Author[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Author': id_author, name**

Answer (score 1):

El método `getAuthorById` devuelve un observable y hay que suscribirse para obtener el valor:

```
getAuthorbyId(id: string) {
    this.authorService.getAuthorById(id).subscribe(autor => {
        this.autor = autor;
  })
}
```

Comment: Acabo de hacer lo que dices y me sigue saliendo este error: Type 'Author[]' is missing the following properties from 
type 'Author': id_author, name

Comment: Ese error indica que `getAuthorById` te está devolviendo un arreglo de Author en lugar de uno solo. El servidor tiene este código `return res.json(response.rows);` La respuesta ha de tener el formato `[ {} ]` por eso lo interpreta como un arreglo.

Comment: gracias @Lobos,  y como seria la funcion del lado del servidor para que me devuelva un author solo, en vez de un arreglo? del lado del servidor hice que me retornara de esta forma  return res.json(response); pero sigue mostrando el mismo error en Angular

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia con node pero si rows es un arreglo podrías tomar el primer elemento: `return res.json(response.rows[0]);`